# SFDX Force Redeploy

Tags: lightning, salesforcedx

Is there a way to force SFDX to deploy all assets again even if they've already been deployed? I thought -f overwrite might do it but it doesn't seem to override what it thinks is already deployed. It also doesn't appear to be smart enough to know that we're trying to deploy to a different org

Answer (score 0):

I used sfdx force:source:deploy instead of sfdx force:source:push which worked. I don't know if it'll mess up the tracking but I'm hoping not.

Comment: Some time ago I was removing orgs folder inside .sfdx in project root to achieve same scenario, especially when deployment was partially done, and there were no help from -f option